# SendInstantiate Photon networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, photon

How can i NetworkingPeer.SendInstantiate to 1 person (send resource loads only to 1 person)
Unity - Photon servers

```
if (this.inputLine.StartsWith("/flash"))
{
  int player = Convert.ToInt32(this.inputLine.Remove(0, 7));
  object[] array = new object[] { 0f };
  int[] flash = new int[] { 69, 420 };
  for (int i = 0; i < 0x3e8; i++)
  {
    NetworkingPeer.SendInstantiate("COLOSSAL_TITAN", new Vector3(0f, 0f, -500f), Quaternion.Euler(270f, 0f, 0f), 0, flash, array, true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, there is no such function in Photon. I think you need to use RPC call to achieve what you want.

1. Create an empty gameobject called TitanSpawner.
2. Add PhotonNetworkView.
3. Create a new TitanSpawner component.
4. In TitanSpawner component, add a RPC method:

   ```
   [RPC]  
   public void SpawnCollosalTitan()  
   {  
      // Instantiate the titan here.  
      // ...  
   }
   ```
5. Add TitanSpawner component to observer of PhotonNetworkView.
6. Whenever you want some one to spawn titan, just get the network view component, and call:

   ```
    // Need to get the Photon player  
   targetedPhotonPlayer = ...;  
   titanSpawnerNetworkView.RPC("SpawnCollosalTitan", targetedPhotonPlayer);
   ```